# How do I delete my "./.adobe/Flash_Player" folder?

Tags: flash

I'm not good at Ubuntu. I can't watch hbogo. I googled it and found out that I needed to install `libhal`.  I think I did that but don't know how to check.  But my error code changed so I think I did in fact install it.

So I googled the new error code and it appears that I need to delete the `./.adobe/Flash_Player` folder.

So I clicked on the file cabinet icon on the launcher bar but I can't even find that folder.

I get error code: 3323 corrupt global state store sub error code = 1090519053

This is the thread that says I need to delete the folder, I have same symptons as this poster: forums.adobe.com/thread/964787

Comment: Could you add a reference about where you found that you have to delete that directory? Also the error code that you got?

Comment: I get error code: 3323

corrupt global state store

sub error code = 1090519053

Comment: This is the thread that says I need to delete the folder, I have same symptons as this poster: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/964787

Comment: could you add the link and the error code to your post since the comments could get easily deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you didn't found the directory in question `~/.adobe` was because all files starting on `.` (dot) are hidden by default. If you use a File Manager (Nautilus) you can show all the hidden files using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>, then look for your directory and delete the file, to hide everything again, just press the same key combination. If you want to delete this file using the console/terminal, you can use `rm ~/.adobe/Flash_Player`.